# When does the error migrations occur(entity framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im getting this error:

```
The model backing the 'database' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
```

**But** the problem is that my entities are the same as in the database: same maxlength, if null, same data type.

The error occurs when i update my model, since the database and the model have not the same attribute. But my question is. Is there any other case that this error could occur? It says that the error is in this code:

```
int UserId = (from d in db.Tbl_Users
                         where d.dbUserID == userName && d.dbPassWord == pass
                         select d.dbUser).SingleOrDefault();
```

Everything is its ok, the tables attribute are totally the same(database and model) but when i run the app, the error fire. So, ill repeat the question, **When does the error migrations occur? Is there another escenario that the error fire??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's giving you the error there because it's the first time that you're using the DbContext in your application to call the database. Whenever you ask for database records for the first time in the application Entity Framework will automatically check to see if the model that the DbContext generates is the same as the one already found in the database. Not the database tables themselves, but the *model* that is stored in the database. When it notices that they are different it automatically throws that exception.

To avoid it you'll need to set some sort of initializer to tell Entity Framework what to do if the models don't match. If you're using migrations it would probably look like this (do this before the first time you call for the context):

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, Configuration>());
```

There are also other initializers to use, like DropCreateDatabaseAlways and DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges, but I much prefer the migration one.

Comment: I found out that the the the table has not pk so EF will not work(sin ORM work with PK(correct me if im wrong)). If i use web matrix, could it work?

Comment: I have no idea (never used web matrix). Why don't you have PKs?

Comment: Im the database manager but i am not the one who created it. I dont know what were they thinking

Answer (score 0):

This must be the first time you're using the DbContext class (i.e. connecing to the DB), so that is when the internal data model is built and compared to the database schema.

Edit: you can delete the contents of dbo.__MigrationHistory if you're not using migrations and want to quickly see if it solves the problem.